# How can I substitue namespace in C++ compiling/ preprocessing?

Tags: c++

I have some questions about symbol conflicting in deploy. Let me show the case(for example):

I write a project `foo`, it depends lib `bar` with version `2.9` within `third_party` using git submodule (I got the source code). So I will link it in CMake when compiling my lib `foo`.

Now I have finished my lib and I want to integrate it into a SDK. In this SDK, some other dependencies of it will use lib `bar` too, but in different versions, lower , `0.7`. Now I got problems, I found when I compile SDK, the method I call of `bar` 2.9 in `foo` will go into the `bar` 0.7, which cause crash.

I thinl a solution: Modify all the namespace in `bar` 2.9 source code and compile it to a lib.

How can I do this? substitute namespace in `bar` 2.9 in compiling (too many files)? Somebody tells me a way:

if `bar`'s outtest namespace is `fxxx`, I could define a header `test.hpp` and set a macro:

```
#define fxxx custom_fxxx
```

And get all the sources in `bar` 2.9 inlude it. I don't know if it is OK and if there is another way.

Comment: you can't cure this by macros! Problem is managing dependencies of libraries. You should describe what kind of libraries you have: dynamic (statically link or loaded dynamically), static libraries, header only libraries. Also you should explain what you can modify and what not.

Comment: Is there any way you can make all your various components use the same version of `bar`?  Anything else sounds really dangerous.

Comment: Yes, you can use macros to rewrite code. You can also use an editor and search'n'replace stuff, which is probably more transparent.

Comment: When you link with (static) libraries (of different versions) it is important not to leak any of the types of that library on your own SDK.  Can you rewrite your api to expose (simplified) versions of the (internal) library types? Or in other words can you redesign your API to only export fundamental C++ types or types declared by the API itself. (Note this will also allow you to switch to other libraries later if you need to)

Comment: You should not link stuff together that each depend on different versions of a same external library. That will cause major headaches

Comment: @MarekR In iOS, I find `bar` 0.7 static library with `.a`. But When I see the crash backtrace, It broke in `libbar.dylib`.

Comment: @PaulSanders I can't. This is a big, famous app and has many sub projects. I can't change other's.